# Android: how to have a cropped image after ImageView rotation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, android-imageview

I have a problem with an ImageView that I rotate in a RelativeLayout. Here is my problem:

[image]

How should I do to obtain what I want ?

Thanks !

My java code:

```
 previewImageView.setRotation(rotAngle);
```

My xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.xxxx.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/dark_blue_page"
            />

        <com.xxxx.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/previewImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"

            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you try to put TouchImageView as a child to the SquareImageView >?

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work. Crash : SquareImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: I think the better way is to set a centerCrop to the previewImageView after rotation . somthing like this :previewImageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

Comment: Thanks... I was sure that I tried this parameter but actually not... as it works... Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to wrap the ImageView in the FrameLayout

Like that:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/previewBackgroundImageView" >

     <com.xxxx.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/previewImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

That way the FrameLayout would clip any part of its child views that is beyond the FrameLayout boundaries. That is based on the view attribute [android:clipChildren](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:clipChildren) that have a default value of `true`

Drawbacks: That brings more layouts nesting to the project that could potentially harm the performance of the application. But that one FrameLayout alone would not do any harm by itself.

Comment: Thanks. I initially used CENTER_CROP as suggested by @Bahador Eslami but it didn't fully solved my problem (for reasons really specific to my project). So I finally used you great solution. Thanks !